# How to add seller name in recent orders(my-orders.php) page in woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add seller name of the product in my recent orders table. What changes should i have to make in my-orders.php page.

Comment: which plugin are you using for enabling sellers?

Comment: I am using dokan theme for that

Comment: You will have to check how the seller name is defined by the theme/plugin. e.g. `$seller=get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'seller_term_name' ); echo($seller[0]->name);`
"seller_term_name" should match with the seller term defined in your theme/plugin and "get_the_ID()" should correspond with the order id.